# Instead of input there is something HTML

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I made a simple chat app and I want instead of the user typing their name HTML fill that I have everything but don't know how to do it I will list code bellow

```
        <form action="/create" method="post">
        {{ Auth::user()->name }} // This is what i want 
            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Name"> // In here insted of user typeing it
            <input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Content">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
```